# Черная картинка при выводе изображения

Tags: python

```
'exec(%matplotlib inline)'
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd
x_data = pd.read_csv('olivetti_X.csv');a = []
for i in range(len(x_data)):
  X = np.array(x_data.iloc[i])
  x = X.reshape(64,64)
  plt.imshow(Image.fromarray(x), cmap = plt.get_cmap('gray'))
  plt.show()
```

Не могу понять, из-за чего не выводятся изображения из датасета, помогите разобраться

Comment: А просто через print смотрели, что в x получается?

Comment: Если через print, то получается вывод массива данных размерностью от reshape(64,64)

Comment: Приведите пример какие конкретно у вас там числа выводятся.

Comment: [0.83471072 0.91322315 0.66942149 ... 0.65289259 0.77272725 0.74380165]]
[[0.13636364 0.11983471 0.1322314  ... 0.19421488 0.16528925 0.1570248 ]
 [0.12809917 0.13636364 0.12809917 ... 0.16942149 0.1570248  0.15289256]
 [0.12396694 0.11983471 0.11157025 ... 0.19421488 0.16942149 0.16942149]

Comment: Подозреваю, что если вы используете color map, то надо привести ваши числа к диапазону 0-255 или что-то вроде того. У вас получается всё приводится к 0 в итоге, т.е. чёрному цвету.

Comment: `X = (X * 255).astype(np.uint8)`, пальцем в небо (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47292141/5909792)

Comment: Ого, да Вы гений, спасибо )

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [привести значения к диапазону 0-255](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47292141/5909792):

```
X = (X * 255).astype(np.uint8)
```